# How many of the members of the 104th corps are titan shifters?

Tags: attack-on-titan

So far

> Eren, Annie, and Ymir

have been shown to be titan shifters. From an Attack on Titan wikia I know also

> Reiner and Bertolt are also titan shifters

How many more are known to be titan shifters from the manga? Are there more titan shifters than humans in that division?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the only ones inside the walls.

> there are nine titan powers, Eren currently possesses the attack titan and the founder titan, Reiner has the armored titan, Berthold has the colossal titan and I don't know what is Ymis's titan. there is also a beast titan power that is in the Marleys hands and is said to possess the ability to change regular Eldians into mindless titans using his spinal fluid and then the beast titan is able to control them. and also Anne had the female titan and is now crystallized.

Comment: Two titans left, both of them appeared in manga already.

Answer (score 1):

So far, up until chapter 92

> We were revealed all 9 titan shifters. The manga showed two more, Jaw and Cart, which were the missing two. I will not say who is whom, but to answer your question, yes, only the ones you mentioned are shifters within the troops of 104th squad.

However, in the latest chapter (93)

> We are revealed that Ymir is indeed the Jaw titan, thus we only know 8 shifters.

To answer your question

> Yes, as far as we know, no other titan shifters are present in the members of 104th corps.

But, according to some fan-based theories

> there might be one type of titan shifter among the 104th. But I will not speculate. here